# Coverage for a bus with struct type

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog, uvm

I have a bus of following type

`typedef struct            packed {
      logic                vld;
      logic [ASI_MAX_PCL_CYC_M:0]  cyc;
   } type_t;`

with a certain width say [3:0]

So **type_t [3:0] my_bus_req;**

How do i write a coverpoint which says that at any clock cycle, only one vld is high
i.e my_bus_req[0].vld = 1 and rest = 0. (Only one request coming in )

if the signal wasn't a struct type eg logic [3:0] my_req_bus;
we could have simple done

**coverpoint i iff (my_bus_req[i].vld == 1 && $onehot(my_bus_req))**

but not sure how it can be done for a bus of struct type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you made this a packed array, there's no simple expression you can use directly without creating a separate function or casting to an unpacked array.

```
typedef type_t type_unpacked_t[4];
type_unpacked temp;
temp = type_unpacked'(my_bus_req);
...
coverpoint i iff (temp[i].vld == 1 && temp.sum() with (int'(item.vld)) == 1)
```